# Optional Subdirectory Internal Redirect, Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently use this code to silently call another php file by using the file name as a get parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  blog/([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   repost_p.php?post=%1  [L]
```

what if I wanted to make the file name a fake subdirectory, and  add a file name as a second get parameter?

how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)   /repost_p.php?path=$1  [L]
```

Then in the repost_p.php file you can filter the path variable to find out the subdirectories.

```
$path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] ? '';
$params = explode('/', $path);

//params is now an array with all subdirectories.
//Make sure you validate each one for valid input! This can also be used for sql injection
```